# Django - How can I send absolute url for a model from views.py to another python script?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm pretty new to Django and am trying to make a breadcrumbs module. It works pretty well, except I'm having trouble trying to link back to URLs which need a primary key.
I've got a `breadcrumbs.py` file which simply looks up the list of keywords in a list and adds HTML in the form of list items.

The problem is to link back to, for example, the profile of a user, I need to send the absolute_url for that profile to `breadcrumbs.py`. However, since I'm calling the `get_breadcrumbs` function from within views.py, I can't directly send the request object as an argument in extra context.

**models.py:**

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, blank= True, default=Role.get_default)
    image = models.ImageField(default='profile_pics/default.png', upload_to = 'profile_pics')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.user.username}'s profile"
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profile", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

**views.py:**

```py
from apps.backend_utils.breadcrumbs import get_breadcrumbs

class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'users/users_profile.html'
    extra_context = {
        'breadcrumbs': get_breadcrumbs(['home']), 
        'page_title' : 'Profile', 
    }
```

**breadcrumbs.py:**

```py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

breadcrumb_lookup = {
    'home': {
        'title' : 'home', 
        'url_name': 'home',
        'icon_class' : 'fas fa-home',
    },
    'profile': {
        'title' : 'Profile',
    },
    ...[Code omitted]...
}

for k, v in breadcrumb_lookup.items():
    if 'url_name' in v.keys(): 
        v.update({'url': reverse_lazy(v['url_name'])})
    breadcrumb_lookup.update({k: v})

def get_breadcrumbs(crumb_list: list):
    return [breadcrumb_lookup[c] for c in crumb_list if c in breadcrumb_lookup]
```

I'm using it in my template as:

```py
{% for crumb in breadcrumbs %}
    {% if crumb.title == 'home' %}
        <li class="nav-home">
    {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item">
    {% endif %}
        {% if crumb.url %}
            <a href="{{ crumb.url }}">
        {% else %}
            <a href="#">
        {% endif %}
            {% if crumb.icon_class %}
                <i class="{{ crumb.icon_class }}"> </i>
            {% else %}
                <span>{{ crumb.title }}</span>
            {% endif %}
        </a>
    </li>
    {% if not forloop.last %}
        <li class="separator">
            <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I *could* get the request from the `dispatcher` method, and then save it in `extra_context`. Then I could modify the `get_context` method to pass the absolute_url to the `get_breadcrumbs` method, but that seems like a lot of work for a simple functionality (and I'm guessing there's a better way).

```py
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'users/users_profile.html'
    extra_context = {
        'page_title' : 'Profile', 
    }
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra_context['profile_url'] = request.user.profile.get_absolute_url()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['breadcrumbs'] = get_breadcrumbs(['home', 'profile'], profile_url = context['profile_url'])
```

Alternatively, I could also just redirect the user to their own profile by changing the URL to another view to redirect to the user's profile, but this just seems like a bad way to do things.

```py
class ProfilePageRedirectView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView): 
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.user.profile.get_absolute_url())
```

I know Django is opinionated, and would love to learn how to do this right.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a custom template tag that encapsulates the logic of breadcrumbs generation. Template or inclusion tags could use the context of the request `takes_context=True` and that way you will have access to the currently logged-in user as well you can explicitly pass another context, like explicit breadcrumbs section e.g. `{% breadcrumbs 'home' %}`.

Comment: @rootart any documentation for that? Could you please share an example of how that's work in this case?

Comment: You could check this code to get some inspiration https://github.com/tj-django/django-view-breadcrumbs/blob/main/view_breadcrumbs/templatetags/view_breadcrumbs.py#L76 as well as official Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags